# Reset AD user account password and email credentials to user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, smtp, passwords, powershell-4.0

**Task:** I use the following code to import one column csv with user "samaccountname" and I use this one liner code `-join (33..126|%{[char]$_}|Get-Random -Count 14)` to generate a random password which is stored in the variable `$newpwd` followed by resetting the user password and outputting the password to host.

This works just find. However, I would like to send this new password to the AD Account email address. I have a working local smtp, and have written a simple Send-Mailmessage script for this purpose, however I just don't know how to add the "displayname, samaccountname, and new password" in the body of the message. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# Set the new password
$newpwd = -join (33..126|%{[char]$_}|Get-Random -Count 14)
$newPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$newpwd" -Force
# Import users from CSV
Import-Csv "C:\Userlist.csv" | ForEach-Object {
$samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"

# Reset user password.
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samAccountName -NewPassword $newPassword -Reset

# Force user to reset password at next logon.
Set-AdUser -Identity $samAccountName -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
Write-Host "Your user account $samAccountName password has been update to: $newpwd"

}
# Output

Your user account jdoe password has been updated to: 9-5R_*&{/x%#Oh
```

Comment: Try using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.  It works quite well, and the help files are quite self-explanatory.  Build your `$MessageBody` string and you're good to go.

Comment: @Mathew, thanks for such a prompt response. Yes, I can use Send-MailMessage cmdlet, but I would like to know how to get the displayname to include in my message. Any ideas? or do you have a sample you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to a machine with the AD cmdlets atm.  If you can use `Get-ADUser` to display the info after you've created the account, you should be able to see the DisplayName in the return object.  I think the command would be `(Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName).DisplayName` to just get the DisplayName

Comment: Once you reset the password, how is the user going to check their email to get the password?

Comment: Thanks Mat. @Jawad, the users emailaddress is of a different domain. Example... the samaccountname is jdoe@supportdomain.com but the emailaddress value is jdoe@externaldomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

**Note / Warning:** If you reset the password of a domain user, the user will no longer be able to sign in with the new password. Even if you send that password to the user after reset, the last known password that user is aware of will no longer function and prevent them from accessing their mailbox (even mobile).

---

When you run the command, `Get-ADUser`, it only gives you the `basic` information about the account without all the properties. `Get-Member` will give you basic properties that the Get-ADUser will return.

```
Get-ADUser <identity> | get-member
```

Now, in order to get the properties that are not available by default, you can ask for these properties by using their names or using `*` to get ALL properties. For larger searches, this might take longer than expected. I would recommend only defining fields you need to retrieve. *`<Identity> is your sameaccountname`*

```
$user = Get-ADUser <identity> -Properties DisplayName, SamAccountName, Mail

# OR following command that will load up "every" property into $user.
$user = Get-ADUser <identity> -Properties *

$user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $newPassword
$user | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True

Write-Output $user.DisplayName
Write-Output $user.SamAccountName
Write-Output $newpwd
```

and to send an email,

```
Send-MailMessage -From administrator@company.com -To $user.Mail -Subject "Password was Reset" -Body "Your password was reset during routine updates. It was set to $newpwd" -SmtpServer xyz.company.com
```

**[See Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)**

**[See Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps)**

**[See Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)**